# What should be assembly-informational-format be set to in GitVersion.yml

Tags: gitversion

My GitVersion.yml looks like below after I picked up the Global configuration from [here](https://gitversion.net/docs/configuration)

But the problem is, this throws the exception when I run gitversion

**Unable to format AssemblyInformationalVersion.  Check your format string: 'InformationalVersion' is not a member of type 'GitVersion.SemanticVersionFormatValues' (Parameter 'propertyOrFieldName')**

I had to remove the 5th line

assembly-informational-format: '{InformationalVersion}'

to make the exception go away.

I tried the following but did not work.

assembly-informational-format: {InformationalVersion} # removed the quotes.

What am I missing.

```
next-version: 0.1.0
mode: mainline
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
assembly-informational-format: '{InformationalVersion}'
increment: Inherit
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ci
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
legacy-semver-padding: 4
build-metadata-padding: 4
commits-since-version-source-padding: 4
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
commit-date-format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
branches:
  master:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^master
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  release:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^releases?[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
    pre-release-weight: 1000
  feature:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: useBranchName
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^features?[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  pull-request:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: PullRequest
    increment: Inherit
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    tag-number-pattern: '[/-](?<number>\d+)[-/]'
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^(pull|pull\-requests|pr)[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  hotfix:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^hotfix(es)?[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  support:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: ''
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^support[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
    tag: unstable
    increment: Minor
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: false
    track-merge-target: true
    regex: ^dev(elop)?(ment)?$
    tracks-release-branches: true
    is-release-branch: false
ignore:
  sha: []
merge-message-formats: {}
```

Comment: I've raised this as a potential issue here: https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion/issues/2103

Answer (score 2):

So, `InformationalVersion` is set according to the format specified by `assembly-informational-format`. So that's likely what's causing the error.

For example, what I've done is something like:

```
assembly-informational-format: '{MajorMinorPatch}{PreReleaseTagWithDash}+{ShortSha}'
```

Then, when I run GitVersion, I get back:

```
"InformationalVersion":"2.0.0-convert-to-netcore.9+abc123"
```

Again, the documentation is not clear on which variables can be used as part of string interpolation, vs. which variables are set by the various format fields.

**UPDATE**
I noticed my answer seems to contradict the documentation at GitVersion. However, my experience has demonstrated to me that setting `assembly-informational-format` influences the value of `InformationalVersion`, even though `InformationalVersion` is considered a variable and can be used in interpolation. I think this may be a mistake in GitVersion's documentation. Or at best, that `InformationalVersion` can be used as a variable in other formats, but because `assembly-informational-format` is what determines the final value of `InformationalVersion`, this variable cannot be used in the `assembly-informational-format` configuration value.

**Another Update**
OK, I realized that, while the documentation could be better, I've been operating under a misconception about what GitVersion is actually doing/providing. It's not magic (well, it kind of is ;) ), it does require work on your part.

GitVersion is merely calculating some version fields for SemVer and outputs these calculations into a JSON object when you run `GitVersion.exe` (when using the executable). GitVersion also provides some various common "mash-ups" of these fields, e.g. `MajorMinor`, `MajorMinorPatch`, etc. It *also* provides some ways for you to format complete version numbers, e.g. `assembly-file-versioning-format` and `assembly-informational-format`. But in the end, the results of all of these are output to a JSON object.

It is *your* responsibility to pick and choose from this JSON object, how to construct your version number. So, if you want to use the string from `InformationalVersion` as your NuGet package version (for v3 package feeds) which is based on the format specified in `assembly-informational-format`, that's your choice.

GitVersion provides instructions on how you can have this JSON object "converted" into either build variables or environment variables that can be accessed from your build process. It's up to *you* to ensure you configure your build to use these values to achieve your desired versioning scheme. But GitVersion only calculates the major/minor/patch version number and attempts to help you format pre-release and build metadata tags.

This revelation certainly helped me understand better how to configure GitVersion and use it in my build processes.